# Azure File Sync - Multiple Servers

Tags: azure, azure-files

Couldn't find it in the search. Should be a fairly simple answer. Is it possible to sync multiple servers that are in different locations that contain the same data using Azure File Sync? Essentially, I want my users to be able to open File A in Location A, modify it and have the changes saved and replicated to Location B.

If you are familiar with Peer or Panzura, it will be the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, when you create a Sync Group you have one Cloud Endpoint and can have multiple Server Endpoints from Registered Servers which will sync to each other, the whole setup process is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal%2Cproactive-portal).

From the above document under "[Create a Sync Group...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal%2Cproactive-portal#create-a-sync-group-and-a-cloud-endpoint)":

> A sync group defines the sync topology for a set of files. Endpoints within a sync group are kept in sync with each other. A sync group must contain one cloud endpoint, which represents an Azure file share and one or more server endpoints. A server endpoint represents a path on a registered server....

Comment: Thanks, I was pretty sure it did but needed to be pointed in the general direction of documentation. Do you know if Azure files does file lock in a multiple server scenario?